# How can I set the background colour of part of a WPF DataGrid row, depending on column values?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, binding, wpfdatagrid

Say I have a DataGrid with 5 columns, loaded (using AutoGenerateColumns=True) from a custome class collection.  Based on the value in the first, third and fourth columns, I need to set the background of the row with one of the following options:

```
col num:    1    2    3    4    5
 Option1: gray gray gray gray gray
 Option2: gray red  red  gray gray
 Option3: gray gray gray red  red
 Option4: gray blue blue blue blue
```

This needs to be done for each row separately.

I've seen some examples of setting a converter for the row background, but how can I set individual cell backgrounds?

Comment: Do you know what your data context or ItemsSource will be for the grid? the AutoGenerateColumns part of this is where I think it's just not going to work with a template.

Comment: Yes, my ItemSource is a ViewModel property with a List(Of MyCustomPOCO)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to use custom columns, then you can pass the whole row into a converter while using the `ConverterParameter` to specify the current column, that way you can compare all the values:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Column1}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ValueToBrushConverter},
                                    ConverterParameter=1}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Column2}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ValueToBrushConverter},
                                    ConverterParameter=2}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
<!-- ... -->
```

I do not quite that table of yours but you probably can figure out how to return the correct value in the converter on your own.

---

Converter skeleton could be something like this:

```
public class ValueToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 1st Indexer: Columns
    /// 2nd Indexer: Options
    /// </summary>
    Brush[,] _brushMatrix = new Brush[5,4]
    {
        { Brushes.Gray, Brushes.Gray, Brushes.Gray, Brushes.Gray },
        { Brushes.Gray, Brushes.Red, Brushes.Gray, Brushes.Blue },
        { Brushes.Gray, Brushes.Red, Brushes.Gray, Brushes.Blue },
        { Brushes.Gray, Brushes.Gray, Brushes.Red, Brushes.Blue },
        { Brushes.Gray, Brushes.Gray, Brushes.Red, Brushes.Blue }
    };

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        RowDataItem item = value as RowDataItem;
        int currentColumn = int.Parse(parameter as string);
        int currentRowOption;

        #region Internal logic here, e.g
        if (item.Col1 == "I" && item.Col3 == "Love" && item.Col2 == "Converters")
        {
            currentRowOption = 1;
        }
        //...
        #endregion

        return _brushMatrix[currentColumn, currentRowOption];
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so you agree with N8 in the comment above, that i can't use AutoGenerateColumns?

Comment: I have not done very much with DataGrids but if you use AutoGenerateColumns you have a lot less access to the individual parts, maybe there is some way to do it but this seems more straightforward to me.

Comment: H.B., can you please give an example of the actual converter?  I'm having problems.  I don't need the inner logic, but the interface and declaration parts.  Much obliged for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you want a back end code solution, I'm sure you could get the LoadingRow event to check the individual row's datacontext, and find the generated cell that way as well. I haven't done that before though!

Comment: That's a neat idea, but it seems the event does not work well when AutoGenerateColumns=true.  So if that's the case i will probably go with the custom column suggestion.

Comment: actually, this appears not to work, regardless of AutoGenerateColumns being true or false. See herehttp://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/218179/520231.aspx#520231, the moderator's answer.

Comment: while the value has not been bound to the cell, you can still access that row's datacontext, and the cell in question. The link you provided was just assuming the RowBinding happened after the data was bound. But yes, the better way to do this is with xaml data templates. the original answer is the best if you know the exact data you will be displaying in the grid.